# does not contain a definition for 'GetValue'

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I am getting an error in the following dependency property

Error:

> Does not contain a definition for 'GetValue' and no extension method
>   'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My DP:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace NameSpace
{
   public class RadWindowProperties
    {
       public static readonly DependencyProperty ScreenSubtitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScreenSubtitle", typeof(string), typeof(RadWindowProperties), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

       public string ScreenSubtitle
       {
           get
           {
               return (string)this.GetValue(ScreenSubtitleProperty);
           }
           set
           {
               this.SetValue(ScreenSubtitleProperty, value);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well your `RadWindowProperties` class doesn't appear to derive from anything - where are you expecting it to get a `GetValue` method from?

Comment: `GetValue` is defined in `DependencyObject` class.

Comment: Yes i am trying to get a GetValue, so If i inherit the DependencyObject is that ok? I am new to WPF.

Answer (score 3):

Your class must inherit from DependencyObject, just change the class definition:

```
public class RadWindowProperties : DependencyObject
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) GetValue method Returns the current effective value of a dependency property on a dependency object.

for example if you create a dependency property like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundPasswordProperty =
                DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BoundPassword", typeof(string), typeof(PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnBoundPasswordChanged));
```

You can use GetValue method to get the value of particular instance of DependencyObject.see the below code

```
    private static void OnBoundPasswordChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    PasswordBox box = d as PasswordBox;
                    string strValue=GetBoundPassword(d);
    }

public static string GetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp)
            {
                return (string)dp.GetValue(BoundPasswordProperty);
            }
```

so your class must inherit from [DependencyObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx) class before you can use GetValue method.